# typedef with array in c

Tags: arrays, c, typedef

Something wrong with my understanding of typedef for arrays in C.
Code just not worked as expected. I provide some screenshot while debugging this simply code. And you can see there, that only firs element of array[0] was assigned right to 0xff. [1] and [2] elements was not assigned.

Exploring assembly code of change_array function, I noticed, that address of array + 0x28 and array + 0x50 was used for assigning [1] and [2] elements. It looks like TMyArray[10][n] was used.

So, I have no idea how to access array elements in function change_array.

```
    typedef int TMyArray[10];
    TMyArray test_array = {0};

    void change_array(TMyArray * array)
    {
    *array[0] = 0xff;
    *array[1] = 0xff;   // wrong!
    *array[2] = 0xff;   // wring!
    }

    int main()
    {
    change_array(&test_array);
    return 0;
    }
```

[debugger screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AHt5.png)

I would appreciate any explanation of this behavior.

Comment: `[]` has higher precedence than `*`. So you need `(*array)[0] = ..`

Comment: You don't need to use `&` when passing an array as a parameter. Arrays automatically decay to a pointer when used as a function parameter.

Comment: I wonder why you're using a pointer to the array at all. https://godbolt.org/z/bzsjjcahn

Comment: I'm using pointers as result of initialization methods from different modules. Usually it returns pointers to specific structures. I'm not often use C, prefer to use assembly for MCU, But for ARM it's my hard way to go.

Comment: I would discourage you from hiding arrays and pointers behind typedefs. It is a horrible practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unary `*` has lower precedence than the postfix `[]` operator, so the expression

```
*array[1]
```

is parsed as

```
*(array[1])
```

meaning you're trying to dereference the individual array element, which isn't what you want.  Instead, you need to dereference `array` *first* and then index into the result:

```
(*array)[0] = 0xff;
(*array)[1] = 0xff;
(*array)[2] = 0xff;
```

Comment: Exactly yes) It was just my way to "shoot the leg". Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Note that we don't normally pass pointers to arrays, but pointers to the first element of arrays.

```c
typedef int TMyArray[10];

void change_array( TMyArray p ) {  // Would be clearer as identical `int *p`.
   p[0] = 0xff;
   p[1] = 0xff;
   p[2] = 0xff;
}

int main( void ) {
   TMyArray test_array = { 0 };
   change_array( test_array );
}
```

Comment: This is my inheritance from Delphi where is possible to pass array as paramter. And if passed parameter is not a pointer to array, then method will receive just copy of actual data.

Comment: The context of my "answer" was [tag:c]